# Is the verb usage of "ladle" considered verbing?

Tags: verbs, nouns, linguistics, word-formation, verbing

> She ladled water instead of soup...

In this sentence, is "ladled" considered verbing or was it a regular and real verb before?

I know informal English allows things like: "I'll microwave that thing and see what happens" and "I'll Google it...", when people convert nouns into verbs.

Comment: As well as being a noun, "ladle" is lexicalised as a verb, just as "microwave" is.

Comment: [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/ladle) marks 'ladle' as a noun and a verb. Similarly knife, spoon and fork.

Comment: Anything that was verbed more than a century ago, like *ladled* (verbed in the 16th century, after 5 centuries of being only a noun), is no longer considered verbed.

Comment: @PeterShor So is verbed verbed?

Comment: @Dan: The OED says *verbed* was verbed in 1928, so according to my criterion, it still has six years before it's no longer considered verbed.

Comment: @PeterShor So it will be deverbed in 2028.

Answer (score 1):

### From *ladle* to *ladle*, From *verb* to *verb*

It was *verbing/verbification* when it was *verbed/verbified*. The noun *ladle* was verbed to the verb *ladle* long time ago, as early as 1525 per *OED*<sup>**1**</sup>; thus, any use of the verb *ladle* after the first usage of the verb is not *verbing/verbification* anymore. Only the first usage of the verbified verb merits such designation, under normal conditions<sup>**2**</sup>.

Moreover, the name of the linguistics process, *conversion* (and in this case, more specifically *verbing* or *verbification*) came much later than the verb *ladle*, so it wasn't called *verbing* when verbing occured. Per *OED*, the noun *verbing* is from 1766, the noun *verbification* is from 1785, and the noun *conversion* (as a grammar term) is from 1928 (where it was first used as *conversion-noun*, and the stand-alone usage as *conversion* is from 1950). Also per *OED*, the verb *verb* is from 1928 and the verb *verbify* is from 1820 (where these two verbs are themselves products of *verbification*); however, the transitive verb *convert* is much earlier where the sense 'to turn or change into something of different form or properties, to transfrom something immaterial' is from c1384; and the sense 'to change in character or function; to turn (*into, to*)' is from 1557, although *OED* gives the first example in grammar with this sense from 1836. Still, the verb *convert* might have been used to describe such verbing process in olden times.

### Shakespeare's love of *anthimeria* and *verbing*

In the late 1500s and early 1600s, in the times when *conversion* (and *verbing*) was an innovative rhetorical device, *[anthimeria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anthimeria)*, in the hands of influential English writers like W. Shakespeare and G. Chapman; it was a common practice to convert nouns to denominal verbs mainly through *verbing* (without changing the form, zero derivation) and sometimes with *verbification* (derivation with an affix, mainly *-en/-em*). For example, among many others, Shakespeare was the first one to use *champion* as a verb, in *Macbeth* in a1616; *elbow* as a verb, in *King Lear* in 1608; and *ghost* as a verb, in *Antony & Cleopatra* in a1616. Shakespeare also created verbs with affixes like *enshelter, enwheel* which are obsolete now, except in echoes of Shakespeare's use. Chapman was the first one to use *lip* as a verb meaning 'to kiss', in *Eastward Hoe* in 1605; and later Shakespeare used in *Othello* in a1616 also.

There are, of course, earlier examples of *verbing*. Chaucer, another prominent author who influenced the English language, was the first one to use *peace* as a verb, in *Wife of Bath's Tale* in 1395; and of course, Shakespeare used the verb *peace* also about 200 years later, first in his work *Richard II* in 1597.

---

**Addendum**

**1** Surprisingly, the meaning of the first usage of the transitive verb *ladle* is not what you would expect it to be. Per *OED*, it was:

> To fit up (a water-mill) with ladle-boards. Also const. *up.*

and here is the first usage from 1525:

> Ladillyng of myll, makyng of the flodde yates. 
> <sub>W. H. Turner *Select. Rec. Oxf.* (1880) 55</sub>

In modern English, it would read: 'Ladling of mill, making of the flood gates'. This usage refers to another meaning of the noun *ladle*, *ladle-board*, one of the float-boards of a waterwheel (millwheel). In 1533, the verb *ladle* appears in a French learning book by Giles du Wes as "To ladle, *espuisér*." In 1851, it appears in the famous novel *Moby-Dick* by Herman Melville, but used figuratively for a person:

> Stubb was lustily singing out for some one to ladle him up.

And finally, in 1859, *OED* provides a non-figurative usage with the meaning you would expect "to lift out with a ladle":

> Vance ladled out the toddy. 
> <sub>E. Bulwer-Lytton *What will he do with It*?</sub>

**2** *Verbing*/*Verbification* is a potent source of creating new words and neologisms in English, and it is usually a natural process out of need. It can be done to create nonce words for a single occasion, or just for humor. For example, your friend can say "beer me!" to mean "give me a beer!". Thus, if it is not a common verb (or the noun wasn't verbed too long ago) or if it is for a single occassion/need/humor, it can be called *verbing*; even when different people are verbing the same noun in separate occassions.

Although I was curious and I've checked the verb *beer* in *OED*, and its first usage is as early as 1785; however with a more straightforward meaning:

> *intransitive.* To drink or indulge in beer. (*colloquial* and *humorous.*) 
> *He surely had been brandying it or beering*.

And there is also the colloquial phrasal verb *to beer up* with the meaning "to drink beer; to get drunk" from 1884. This tells us that you can verb nouns with different meanings also; and using the denominal verb with the new meaning is *verbing* also. Having said that, many common nouns and tools that people use were probably verbed long time ago (except more recent, technological ones as technology is evolving fast and influencing the language also). For example, the verb *spoon* is from 1715 for the meaning "to lift or transfer by means of a spoon", per *OED*. Even your other examples, the verbed verbs *google* and *microwave*, has been in use quite a while now and their usage is not considered verbing anymore. Per *OED*, the verb *microwave* with the meaning "to cook or heat in a microwave" is from 1976; and  the verb *google* with the meaning "to use the Google search engine" is from 1998.